# OsmDroid: User agent doesn't work with Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, osmdroid

Every example available on the internet tells us to use this line of code to get the user agent (without it the map won't load).

```
osm.osmdroid.config.Configuration.getInstance()
            .load(applicationContext, this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
```

The problem is that *applicationContext* yields "Unresolved reference". Same goes for *this.getPreferences()*.

I've tried to put that code into MainActivity (no fragments) and it works.
Is there any way to replace it in this context?

Comment: Inside a Fragment, you can get access to a Context via either requireContext() or requireActivity(), however these can be null if the Fragment is yet to be attached.

Comment: Cool, how do I deal with the "this.getPreferences()" part?

Comment: Might be mistaken but replacing it with "PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())" as shown [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.osmdroid.config.Configuration) might work

Comment: The getPreferences might simply be just a method that returns ‘PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences’ which is a method on Context, so you can use requireContext/Activity instead of this.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. I'll post working solution below as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

```
    Configuration.getInstance()
                .load(requireContext(), PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireActivity()))
Configuration.getInstance().userAgentValue = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

It's the second PreferenceManager on the list of hints (the one that is not obsolete.

Although I'm not sure if the first line is even necessary.